# Styling Radio buttons underlining text

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling, underline

[image: Below is the sample snapshot of what I want to achieve]

So I'll have the texts: "The Oxford ....real examples" and the phrases that need to be underlined and having a radio option right below (in the picture there is no radio button, but I also need a radio button for users to select).

How can I achieve this with css and javascript?

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: What have you t­ried?

Comment: Hi Derek, I'm stuck at the part about positioning the options below the underlined texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

<kbd>[*`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NRpcn/`*](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NRpcn/)</kbd>

(I have used [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) in my example just for simplicity)

```
var list = ["The", "well known", "meanings", "to give"];    //word list
var output = $("#output"),
    html = output.html();

for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    //Wrap each keyword with <span>
    html = html.replace(new RegExp("(" + list[i] + ")", "i"), "<span>$1</span>");
}

output.html(html);

$("p>span").each(function (i) {              //Create the index for each one
    var x = $(this).offset().left,                  //Get the x
        y = $(this).offset().top,                   //Get the y
        width = +$(this).width(),                   //Get the width
        $select = $("<div>").addClass("select");

    $select.css({
        top: y + 20,
        left: x,
        width: width
    })
        .html(String.fromCharCode(65 + i))          //Set the index (A, B, C...)
        .appendTo("body");                          //Append it to the container
});
```

(The example will auto-recalculate the positions when you resize the window.)

This is one way to achieve it, and there're many other ways to do it. Personally I like this better because this isn't very complicated to understand.

Comment: Thank you Derek. That's nice. 

Btw, can I ask you what's the difference between $('p>span') and $('p span')? What's the ">" for? 

Thanks

Comment: Yes, Thanks Derek. I've tried it out in my case and it works. 
The only minor problems is that because the options are positioned absolute, it may collides with the text below (for example, when the sentence is very long and therefore spanning 2 lines, the option A may cover the text at the next line). Is there anyway to force the next line to recede a little margin?

Comment: @PaulHoang - In my example, I increased the `line-height` to increase the spacing between lines.

Comment: I wonder if there is a nicer solution (because line-height would be applied to all). But it works. Thanks Derek.

Comment: @PaulHoang - Just my two cents, there is no better way to do this except dynamically adding `<br>` which you probably don't want.